# How can I check the input if its a number and over zero?

Tags: c#

I tried it this way but it's ignoring the second part. How can I check if the Input is also over zero? My code:

```
static int err()
{
      int rtn;

      while(!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out rtn) & !(rtn > 0))
      {
            Console.WriteLine("Errormessage");
      }
      return rtn;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the bitwise AND operator by mistake. However, this is also not what you want. (See comments below.) Change the condition to be a logical OR instead:

```
while(!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out rtn) || !(rtn > 0))
// ----------------------------------------------^^
```

See:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/bitwise-and-shift-operators

Comment: @Lemonated I just realised why. It's because if the parsing succeeds, but the number is less than 0, the condition is false. It should be a logical OR instead, as in: `if the input is not a number, or it is less than 0`, then show the error message.

Comment: @Lemonated No problem. :)

Answer (score 1):

[`&` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/bitwise-and-shift-operators#logical-and-operator-) is a bitwise logical AND operator. You need to use [`&&` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/index#conditional-and-operator) which is logical AND.

```
while(!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out rtn) && !(rtn > 0))
{
      Console.WriteLine("Errormessage");
}
```

If your logic is "if it's a number and over zero" to give error message, you can change it to;

```
while(int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out rtn) && (rtn > 0))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Errormessage");
}
```

If your logic is "if it's a number and less or equal to zero" to give error message, you can change it to;

```
while(int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out rtn) && (rtn <= 0))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Errormessage");
}
```

Be aware that, `&&` operator has [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) which means that it does *not* evaluate the second operand since the if first operand is `false`.

Comment: Still not working though. It still ignores the second part

Comment: @Lemonated Changed my post based on what logic you _might_ follow. `&&` operator has short-circuit evaluation. That means if first operand is `false`, it does not evaluate the second operand since it doesn't matter and the result will be `false` no matter what.

Comment: Now I realise the problem. Thank you!

Comment: @Lemonated Glad to help.